# mysql see what users have the select privileges for a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'd like to write a query to select all the mysql users that can select data from a given table in a database. I need to see who can access so a decision can be made higher up as to who can still select data from over there and who shouldn't.
Is there any way to do that?
I tried

> show grants

and selecting from mysql.db but I don't understand it only seems to specify database level privileges and I need to see all the users that can access a certain table.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.user_privileges
WHERE `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` = 'SELECT'

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem? The table name does not exist in the result set. I need something like select username from something where privilege_type = 'select' and table='mytable' resulting in all users that are allowed to select from one table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT grantee
FROM information_schema.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
WHERE table_name = 'mytable'
```

this query worked for me